# JIRA REST API and kerberos authentication

Tags: python, rest, authentication, jira, kerberos

I am struggling with Jira REST API authentication via kerberos. Basic authentication works as expected.

If I access the login page with the web browser (after I did kinit) and then use the generated JSESSIONID in my python script, I can use REST without getting 401. But I have no ide how to do that with my python script, I tried to use requests_kerberos, but when I request the login page, it simply returns the basic login form instead of automatic login.

Do you know how to use JIRA REST API with kerberos authentication?

Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a day of struggle I finally figured it out.

First you have to send an HTTP GET request to `${jira-url}/step-auth-gss`:

```
r = requests.get("https://example-jira.com/step-auth-gss", auth=requests_kerberos.HTTPKerberosAuth())
```

Then you get the JSESSIONID from the cookie header and you can REST away:

```
rd = requests.get(url, headers={"Cookie": "JSESSIONID=%s" % r.cookies['JSESSIONID']})
```

Comment: What JIRA Kerberos plugin are you using for this? Or should this work out-of-the-box?

Comment: I get 404 when I go to set-auth-gss on my Jira. Do I need to enable anything to make this URL work?

Comment: Replying to my own question: this won't work out-of-the-box, I use [Cleito Kerberos plugin](https://www.cleito.com/products/iwaac/documentation/) with all my Tomcat based products. I got it working with Powershell, but still trying to get this fully working from Python.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by VaclavDedik, the first step is to get a valid *JSESSIONID* cookie (along with *atlassian.xsrf.token* and *crowd.token_key* cookies if you use Crowd for user management and SSO) upon successful Kerberos authentication on a private Jira resource / URL.

In Python, the PycURL package makes it very easy to authenticate with Kerberos. You can install it on Windows/Mac OS/Linux either with *easy_install* or *pip*. The PycURL package relies on *libcurl*. You will need to check that your *libcurl* version is >=7.38.0 as the HTTPAUTH_NEGOTIATE directive was introduced in that very version.

Then, it is as simple as:

```
import pycurl

curl = pycurl.Curl()

# GET JSESSIONID
curl.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "")
curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPAUTH, pycurl.HTTPAUTH_NEGOTIATE)
curl.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, ':')
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, <ANY_JIRA_PRIVATE_URL>)
curl.perform()

# Then REST request
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, <YOUR_JIRA_REST_URL>)
curl.perform()

curl.close()
```

Please, check out the following page for detailed examples in Python, PowerShell and Groovy: https://www.cleito.com/products/iwaac/documentation/integrated-windows-authentication-for-non-browser-clients/

Though this is the official documentation of the Cleito IWAAC plugin mentioned by Xabs, this will work with any server-side Kerberos plugin for Jira